# Overlay too big when actual image resized

Tags: html, css

Sorry for asking this basic question, but can you guys figure this out, here is the code first of all

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .image {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .5s ease;
      background-color: #008CBA;
    }
    .container:hover .overlay {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .text {
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
  <p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Now this is the original code (got it from the web). now if i try and put another image here and change the width of image to 50% (as the image was being stretched a lot, thus making a really big image) then although the image size was reduced the overlay was having a larger width anyone help me ?

Comment: You forgot two things: 1) to link the image and 2) to ask a question. Can you please describe what you want to happen? It's really not clear.

Comment: I meant to say that if i change the width of the image in the code then it will result in the overlay(the blue cover that comes when i hover over the image ) size isn't changing.

Comment: The overlay's width is set to `100%`. If you want less than that, set it to less than that.